# Efficient strided slicing along a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, indexing, slice

Within a pandas dataframe column I would like to (efficiently) select rows by slice at a given incremental offset. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

k = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9))

# Here I can only select 1 element per stride. Would like to select n elements
a = k[0::3]
b = k[1::3]

# Here a copy is made. Would prefer a view of the above.
b.combine_first(a)
Out[11]: 
   0
0  0
1  1
3  3
4  4
6  6
7  7
```

Is there an efficient way to select slices from a column at an incremental offset? Thanks.

Comment: what exactly is your end goal here?

Comment: I think OP wants intervals (of rows) in one slice, for example 0..1, 3..4, 6..7 (or 0..3, 10..13, 20..23, etc)

Comment: Here is an example context: I have for 3 sensors I have 10 sensor readings each (typically a 10 x 3 matrix). These readings are laid out along a (30 x 1 ) column. I wish to aggregate, say, the first 2 readings for each sensor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure pandas, in this case, you can use `k.groupby((k.index / 2) % 2)`. The dataframes sent to the groupy will be strided as you suggest. If you just want the dataframe, `k[(k.index / 2) % 2 == 0]`. Or the method you're using is fine.

Comment: Would something like,

`m = b.values()
n = m.reshape(3, -1, order='F')
n[0:2, :]
array([[0, 3, 6],
       [1, 4, 7]])`

work as well? (efficiency wise; I think groupby sometimes will copy the data)

Comment: @user3662899 I was going to suggest using numpy transposes (if you are actually working with matrices and for some reason store them in dataframes), but it won't work in general if the length isn't divisible by your stride. It also won't work if your index has missing values. But if you are really working with matrices you should use numpy.

Comment: Ended up getting a numpy view from the values attribute and manipulating things that way. The answer given is an alternative way of grouping things, however.